# Split data frame in half, keeping the column names

Tags: r, data-binding, dataframe

I have long data.frame of trading statistics, so in order to fit them into a page I took out the most important ones and put them into two object "hemrik" and "hemrici"

```
hemrik<-tstats[,c("Num.Trades","Net.Trading.PL","Avg.Trade.PL","Largest.Winner","Largest.Loser","Percent.Positive")]
hemrici<-tstats[,c("Profit.Factor", "Max.Drawdown","Profit.To.Max.Draw","Max.Equity","Min.Equity","End.Equity")]
```

I tried several ways to merge them yet keep the columns names. I manage to merge them 
    result<-(hemrik,hemrici) but they the columns have names of the hemrik table and it does not work.

I would it to look like in the attached picture. Is it possible, please?

[image]

Comment: cbind(hemrik,hemrici)

Comment: To view them stacked once, you can write `hemrik;hemrici`, or else I would try `list(hemrik, hemrici)`.

Comment: Ok, that makes it 2 tables in LaTeX then, but I can live with that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
merged <- cbind(hemrik, hemrici[, 2:ncol(hemrici)])
```

For data manipulation and management, this will let you combine the two dataframes- it binds the columns side-by-side, but only takes columns 2 and up from the second sheet so the names aren't duplicated.

I don't know of any way to display the datasets one above the other in R "cleanly". If you want to see them you can obviously scroll up through the terminal output.

For final output/display, exporting both sets to a .csv or other format and using a spreadsheet program such as Excel is probably your best bet.

Comment: I tried this, but it puts them side by side, I woudl need to put one below the other as in the picture....

Comment: If you just want to display them one below the other, exporting them as .csvs and use Excel or Google's Spreadsheets thing is probably the easiest approach.

Comment: Yeah, just for display I will try the csv, seems like a good idea! 
I would need it in LaTeX code as well, is it easily importable into LaTeX then?

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You may get more upvotes this way.

Comment: I've had some good success with an old Excel2LaTeX plugin- try here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/ It lets you copy and paste basic Excel sheets (i.e., a csv) into basic LaTeX formatting.